# Purpose and meaning of やること in correction

Tags: grammar, syntax

I'm trying to understand a correction in a sentence. I wrote:

```
ことをやるクエストがありすぎます。

There are too many quests to do.
```

But it has been corrected to

```
1. やるクエストがありすぎます。

2. やることクエストがありすぎます。

3. やることがありすぎます。
```

I can understand correction #1 as the こと appears to be redundant. But I don't really understand correction #2 or #3. Why is `やること` used? I read the `やること` as `A thing which is done`, but I don't really expect the `こと` at all because `クエスト` is the specific noun being used. But then also in correction #3 `クエスト` is completely removed.

So what does `やること` mean? What's the difference between the corrections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here クエスト and こと are both just nouns. こと means "thing" and やること means "thing(s) to do". Whoever corrected your sentence, Sentence 2 is ungrammatical. Sentence 3 is a correct sentence but it just means "There are too many things to do".